# Convert Excel Formula to Word Formula

Tags: excel, ms-word, excel-formula

I have created a formula in Excel that works fine, but when I put it into a MS Word table, it doesn't seem to work. The formula adds up a column of prices when the resulting column has a specific word in.

The formula is:

```
=SUMIF(E:E, "Yes", D:D)
```

Example:

[image]

Is this possible to do? If so can anyone help converting this so it will work in MS Word.

Thanks, Adam.

Comment: No, Word doesn't not have Excel functions. You can't create this formula in Word. What you could do is embed an Excel workbook in the Word document using Paste Special.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify which version of Word you are using.
MS Word does have a limited number of functions that you can use for math operations in a table.

In order to get your table to work in Word, in Excel column F add a formula:

```
=IF(E4="Yes",D4,0)
```

Fill down to include the formula in every cell of your table in column F.
Word will sum all the values in a column but you cannot have a blank cell in the column, so you need to have a zero and not a blank cell when the "Yes" is not present.

Copy and paste your table to Word. Add a row for a Total. Depending on which verion of Word you are using, find the Table...Formula editor, and type in the last row of the third column

```
=SUM(ABOVE)
```

Your total will display 50.